# How to know if an "includes" call was made while working with a single record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, activerecord

**Motivation**

The motivation was that I want to embed the serialization of any model that have been included in a Relation chain. What I've done works at the relation level but if I get one record, the serialization can't take advantage of what I've done.

**What I've achieved so far**

Basically what I'm doing is using the method `includes_values` of the class `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which simply tells me what things have been included so far. I.e

```rb
> Appointment.includes(:patient).includes(:slot).includes_values
=> [:patient, :slot]
```

To take advantage of this, I'm overwriting the `as_json` method at the `ActiveRecord::Relation` level, with this initializer:

```
# config/initializers/active_record_patches.rb
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    def as_json(**options)
      super(options.merge(include: includes_values)) # I could precondition this behaviour with a config
    end
  end
end
```

What it does is to add for me the option `include` in the `as_json` method of the relation.

So, the old chain:

```
Appointment.includes(:patient).includes(:slot).as_json(include: [:patient, :slot])
```

can be wrote now without the last include:

```
Appointment.includes(:patient).includes(:slot).as_json
```

obtaining the same results (the `Patient` and `Slot` models are embedded in the generated hash).

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem is that because the method `includes_values` is of the class `ActiveRecord::Relation`, I can't use it at the record level to know if a call to `includes` have been done.

So currently, when I get a record from such queries, and call `as_json` on it, I don't get the embedded models.

And the actual problem is to answer:

> how to know the included models in the query chain that retrieved the
>   current record, given that it happened?

If I could answer this question, then I could overwrite the `as_json` method in my own Models with:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  extend Associations

  def as_json(**options)
    super(options.merge(include: included_models_in_the_query_that_retrieved_me_as_a_record))
  end
end
```

**One Idea**

One Idea I have is to overwrite the `includes` somewhere (could be in my initializer overwriting directly the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class, or my `ApplicationRecord` class). But once I'm there, I don't find an easy way to "stamp" arbitrary information in the Records produced by the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution feels quite clumsy and there might be better options out there.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(**options)
    loaded_associations = _reflections.each_value
      .select { |reflection| association(reflection.name).loaded? }
      .map(&:name)

    super(options.merge(include: loaded_associations))
  end
end
```

Note that this only loads 1st level associations. If `Appointment.includes(patient: :person)` then only `:patient` will be returned since `:person` is nested. If you plan on making the thing recursive beware of circular loaded associations.

Worth pointing out is that you currently merge `include: ...` over the provided options. Giving a user no choice to use other include options. I recommend using [`reverse_merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-reverse_merge) instead. Or swap the placements around `{includes: ...}.merge(options)`.